# Endpointnotfoundexception : active endpoint raising error sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, async-await

We are working on an ecommerce project where data are fetched from RESTfull webservices. We are using the `async-await` programming model.

Some services are being requested using `ChannelFactory` class and since we cannot have async approach using ChannelFactory nor does the webservice provides us, so we are using a different approach as shown below.

```
var customerLocationTask = Task.Run(() => new OrderService().GetCustomerLocation(customerId));
var customerCountryTask = this.CmsCustomerCountryCode(customerId);

await Task.WhenAll(customerLocationTask, customerCountryTask);
```

Here, we are requesting 2 webservices in an unnatural async approach and our webservice are being called in synchronous fashion using `ChannelFactory`. And the code for `CmsCustomerCountryCode` is:

```
public async Task<string> CmsCustomerCountryCode(string customerId)
    {
        OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
        Customer customer = await Task.Run(() => orderService.GetCustomer(customerId, ResponseFormat.json));
        return customer.BillToAddress.Country;
    }
```

The issues here is sometimes we get `Endpointnotfoundexception` in `CmsCustomerCountryCode` method. Is that a network issue or our async approach is not correct ?

Comment: Besides the problem in question, are you aware that using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET will result in jumping from thrtead pool thread to thread pool thread making your application slower and consuming more resources?

Comment: @PauloMorgado so how we can we prevent that here ?

Comment: Just don't use `Task.Run` on ASP,NET.

Comment: @PauloMorgado ok will that rectify the existing issue ?